# Vimeo Video Thumbnail in an ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, vimeo-api, vimeo-android

I am developing an Android app which should display a list of video thumbnails in `RecyclerView`. A new activity will then play the video for selected thumbnail. 
How do I set `com.vimeo.networking.model.Picture` to Android `ImageView`?

My code:

```
mVimeoClient.fetchNetworkContent(VIDEO_URI, new ModelCallback<VideoList>(VideoList.class) {
           @Override
           public void success(VideoList videoList) {
                ArrayList<Video> videoArrayList = videoList.data;
               Video video = videoArrayList.get(0);
               ArrayList<com.vimeo.networking.model.Picture> arrayListPics = video.pictures.sizes;
               // imageView.setImageDrawable((Drawable) pictureAL.get(0));
               imageView.setImageBitmap( (Bitmap) arrayListPics.get(0));
           }
           @Override
           public void failure(VimeoError error) {
           }
        });
}
```

The `setImageBitmap()` And `setImageDrawable()` throws

```
java.lang.ClassCastException
```

Comment: What is `Pictures`?

Comment: @NileshRathod Hi, sorry for the typo. it is com.vimeo.networking.model.Picture

Comment: What is this line doing?
ArrayList<com.vimeo.networking.model.Picture> arrayListPics = video.pictures.sizes;

Comment: @EjazAhmad Hi, video.pictures.sizes returns a ArrayList of com.vimeo.networking.model.Picture  of all sizes.

Answer (score 3):

The `Picture` object (the one returned from `arrayListPics.get(0)`) in the `vimeo-networking` library isn't a `Bitmap` and therefore can't be cast to one. The `Picture` object has a field on it called `mLink` which can be access via `Picture#getLink()`. This will return a URI string which you then can set on your `ImageView`.

The simplest code you could use to get this working is:

```
    // The ImageView you want to put the thumbnail in
    ImageView yourImageView = <insert your ImageView here>;
    // The video whose thumbnail you want
    Video yourVideo = <insert your Video here>;
    // The collection of `Picture` objects associated with this video.
    // Each `Picture` in this "collection" is a different size
    PictureCollection yourVideosPictures = yourVideo.getPictures();
    // Get the first thumbnail/picture from this collection (not recommended)
    Picture videoThumbnailPicture = yourVideosPictures.getPictures().get(0);
    // The URI to the image of the thumbnail
    String videoThumbnailUri = videoThumbnailPicture.getLink();
    // Convert the String URI to an actual URI object
    final Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoThumbnailUri);
    yourImageView.setImageURI(uri);
```

I say this is the simplest because there are more things you *should* do when setting an image uri. One thing is you should base the `Picture` your grab from `yourVideosPictures` based on the width of your `ImageView` so that you're not needlessly pulling down a larger image than you need.

You should also *probably* not just set the image URI directly onto `yourImageView`, but instead you should use some image caching library (or some caching implementation).

I'd suggest looking into Picasso, Glide, or Fresco. Or just google "Image caching on Android".

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using [Glide 4.x](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

First of all, import the lib on your project:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
```

Since the `Pictures` class contains an Uri as the others stated, you can use Glide to download the image for you effortlessly as follows.

```
// Get your ImageView
ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.your_image_view);
// Get your thumbnails
ArrayList<com.vimeo.networking.model.Picture> arrayListPics = video.pictures.sizes;
// Load them using Glide
Glide.with(this) // Assuming "this" is your Activity, but you can also use any context here
        .load(arrayListPics.get(0).getLink())
        .into(iv);
```

That way it won't matter where is the thumbnail located (Network, file, resources), Glide will load it for you.

You can also apply some transformations or use placeholders by using Glide's [`RequestOptions`](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/request/RequestOptions.html) class. [Read more on how to use it here](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/options.html).

Answer (score 1):

Please user Picasso library to load image in Image-view.

In gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

in your adapter class

```
mVimeoClient.fetchNetworkContent(VIDEO_URI, new ModelCallback<VideoList>(VideoList.class) {
           @Override
           public void success(VideoList videoList) {
                ArrayList<Video> videoArrayList = videoList.data;
               Video video = videoArrayList.get(0);
               ArrayList<Pictures> arrayListPics = video.pictures.sizes;


Picasso.get().load(arrayListPics.get(0).getpath).into(view);
           }
           @Override
           public void failure(VimeoError error) {
           }
        });
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't the image caching library, it's the way JoeYo is trying to get the path to the image.